# A question about symmetric bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

If b is an indefinite symmetric bilinear form is it nondegenerate?
And conversely if b is nondegenerate is it positive/negative definite or indefinite?
How can i start to prove this?
Note:Edited and changed the question

Comment: A bilinear form is continuous, so nondegenerate $\leftrightarrow$ positive or negative definite. EDIT:I assumed finite dimensions.

Comment: But I don't use continuity here.I have a b bilinear form on V (that is finite dimensional real vector space ).

Comment: I don't think that a bilinear form in finite dimensions can be discontinuous.

Comment: The point is that a bilinear form in FD is actually a matrix, let it be $B$. Let $b$ be the largest entry of the matrix and $B_m$ the matrix with all entries equal to $b$. Then obviously $||B||\le ||B_m||$ but we already know that $||B_m||$ is finite, so $||B||$ is finite also, so $B$ is bounded thus continuous.

Comment: Thanks but I need the proof from simple definitions.I don't use continuity on my work (again).

Comment: The examples of the zero matrix (indefinite but degenerate), the identity matrix (nondegenerate and positive definite) and the diagonal matrix $(1,-1)$ (nondegenerate and indefinite) resolve both questions in the negative.

Answer (score 3):

$b$ is **indefinite** iff its matrix representation $B$ has both positive and negative eigenvalues; $b$ is **nondegenerate** iff $B$ has no zero eigenvalues. So,

- an indefinite $b$ can be degenerate (e.g. $B=\operatorname{diag}(1,0,-1)$);
- a nondegenerate $b$ can be positive definite, negative definite or indefinite (examples: consider $B=1,\ B=-1$ and $B=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$.)